# extracting z3::expr from z3::context by name

Tags: c++, z3

- I need to manipulate some `z3::expr`'s from multiple code places.
- I thought I would only move the `z3::context` around, and
- extract the expressions by name.

Here is what I have in mind:

```
z3::expr x = ctx.constant("x",some_sort); // insert x to context
```

Then extract it from the context according to its name:

```
z3::expr e = ctx.getExprByName("x"); // this API doesn't exist
```

I couldn't find something like this in the API.
Am I missing something? or is it just not possible?

Comment: ASTs/exprs have unique identifiers that you can use like a name, see `Z3_get_ast_id` https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/742be835031e824c371f64d6392442150c923c65/src/api/z3_api.h#L4604 I don't think there's an easy way to find those ASTs in the new context though. Alternatively, once you have two contexts (not necessarily the same), you can use `Z3_translate` to translate expressions between them.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger so it seems that there should also be something like `Z3_ast Z3_API Z3_get_ast_id(Z3_context c, unsigned code);` for the actual extraction, but I can't seem to find such a thing. Also, since I'm using the cpp interface, I would need to go back and forth from `z3::expr` to `Z3_ast`, but I only found **one** of them, namely: `inline expr to_expr(context & c, Z3_ast a)`.
`

Comment: Since you're creating the expression yourself for `x`, it might be best to simply keep track of it outside of z3. Keep your own associative map which manages everything you put in. Once z3 starts munging the internal representation, what you get back may not look at all like what you put in even if you could do that. (Of course this all depends on what you're trying to do in the first place. Perhaps a better question to ask is what exactly are you trying to achieve?)